# Sum of Multiplication of each number with sum of other numbers of an array in rotational manner

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures

Example:

Input : `[4 3 5 1]`
Output: `118`

Explanation:

```
4*(3+5+1)=>36
3*(4+5+1)=>30
5*(4+3+1)=>40
1*(4+3+1)=>12
Therefore, (36+30+40+12=)118
```

What would be the code to implement it?

Comment: The fourth line should be `1*(4+3+5)=>12`

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sum` with generator comprehension:

```py
lst = [4, 3, 5, 1]

output = sum(x * (sum(lst) - x) for x in lst)
print(output) # 118
```

If there the list is long, then you might want to pre-calculate `sum(lst)` and store it in a separate variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain that result by subtracting the sum of squares from the square of the sum:

```
a = [4,3,5,1]

sum(a)**2 - sum(n**2 for n in a)  # 118
```